# How can I edit a block of text in memory using python before writing the text to a file?

Tags: python, csv, scripting, text-parsing

I have a script to download text Block data from the SEC's EDGAR database.  The data is extracted accurately.  However, the text contains multiple sequential spaces (x20) and CRLF's (x0A xOD).

I need to be able to remove the commas and superfluous CRLF's and spaces, then write the entire text contents into a CSV file for later analysis.

I am not a python programmer, but I am using python for this task because the XBRL parsing program has a python interface.

I need to do this task for about 6,000 individual observations, so it is not something I want to attempt manually.

I have searched extensively, including buying and perusing two python textbooks, but I cannot determine how to edit the text before attempting to write it to the CSV file.

Here is a representative print-out of the raw data prior to writing to file.  Note that there should be 5 comma delimited fields, with everything after the date written to a single cell.

DocumentType    EntityName  CIK PeriodEndDate   PPE_Policy
10-K    CONOLOG CORP    23503   7/31/2012

**Property and Equipment**

Property and equipment are carried at cost

```
                  less allowances for depreciation. Depreciation is computed by

                  the straight-line method over the estimated useful lives of

                  the assets which range between three (3) and thirty-nine(39)

                  years. Depreciation was $16,560 and $14,598 for the fiscal 

                  years ended July 31 2012 and 2011 respectively. Repairs and

                  maintenance expenditures which do not extend the useful lives

                  of the related assets are expensed as incurred. Gains and

                  losses on depreciable assets retired or sold are recognized

                  in the consolidated statement of operations in the year of

                  disposal</font></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you've already attempted, but if you download the doc and assign it to a variable, you can then do string operations to that doc. For instance (in pseduo-python):

```
doc = downloaded_xbrl
edited_doc = doc.replace('\x20','') --removes x20, replaces with nothing
csv.write(edited_doc)
```

A link to the python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting